# Bugzilla-VCS installation Error in Extension.pm

Tags: perl, svn, integration, bugzilla

While installing the bugzilla-vcs extension for SVN integration on My windows server 2008, I have encountered this issue. After a lot of searching on google i have finally run out of options. Can somebody assist me in resolving this issue. I am absolutely unfamiliar with perl so am not able to do much this error. The error log is as follows...

```
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v5.6.10-log

"my" variable $vcs_repos masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 180.
"state" variable @_ masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 196.
"my" variable $self masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 208.
"state" variable @_ masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 208.
syntax error at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 145, near "$type qw(Bzr Cvs Git Hg Svn)"
Global symbol "$type" requires explicit package name at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 147.
syntax error at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 172, near "}"
Can't use global @_ in "my" at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 179, near "= @_"
syntax error at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 189, near "}"
Can't use global @_ in "my" at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 196, near "= @_"
syntax error at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 201, near "}"
Can't use global @_ in "my" at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 208, near "= @_"
Global symbol "$args" requires explicit package name at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 209.
syntax error at ./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm line 211, near "}"
./extensions/VCS/Extension.pm has too many errors.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Extension.pm line 68.
```

Comment: This bug has already been reported in the google code repo: https://code.google.com/p/bugzilla-vcs/issues/detail?id=29 . Not much you can do unless you want to start hacking the code and fixing the errors yourself!

Comment: Yup i saw that and starred the bug as well. It seems that there is not much happening with this extension for bugzilla. The last release was done in Oct 2010. I am in dire need of a solution to integrate Bugzilla with our SVN installation to track commits against bugs. I am surprised how difficult this is.

Comment: Presumably you've seen the [Bugzilla SCM integration list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons#Integration_with_Source_Code_Management_programs)?

Comment: Yes i did, My options are limited by the fact that I am trying to do this on a Windows Server. Also I am using VisualSVN, not sure what will be the implication of it. I've already tried using SCMBug but i realized it has been abandoned. Trying the other options now.

Answer (score 2):

It was able to solve the syntax error issues with a couple very minor code edits on Ubuntu I expect the same would work on windows but I haven't tried it.

in VCS/Extension.pm line 145

change

> foreach my $typl qw(Bzr Cvs Git Hg Svn) {

to

> my @types = qw(Bzr Cvs Git Hg Svn);
>
> foreach my $type (@types) {

and VCS/lib/Commit.pm line 130

> foreach my $key qw(revision revno author message uuid) {

to

> my @keys = qw(revision revno author message uuid);
>
> foreach my $key (@keys) {